# Unity5 project does not build for PC Standalone, on Windows with external Visual Studio version (2017)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

Although it's only remotely related to programming, here it goes:

Since last week, I've been playing with *Unity (5.6.0f3 **Community** x64)* on *Win 10 (x64)* - using *Visual Studio (2017 **Community**)* as attached editor, as *Unity* "requires" -, and started with the [[Unity]: Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) (first of them). For a few days everything went just fine, but then, building for *PC Standalone* target, stopped working. *Google*ing and checking the forums, didn't help finding information about this exact behavior:

[image: PC Standalone build]

As seen on the *Build Settings* dialog (moved to the right), there are no (*Target Platform* or *Architecture*) combo-boxes allowing to specify build parameters. Errors are on the left side.

**Notes** (about the current behavior):

- First guess was that the tutorial project became somehow messed up, so I created a new one from scratch (a dummy / simple one containing one *Sphere* having attached a *Rigidbody* and a *C#* script that applies forces based on user input), but it behaves the same (this is the project build output in the above image)
- *WebGL* build runs just fine (loads in browser); this is the workaround currently used, but it takes ages to complete
- *Play*ing (obviously) also works (needless to say that things are *OK* in *VStudio*, no complains from *csc*), **!!!but!!!** after trying (and failing) to build, *Play*ing no longer works (reloading the project is the only way to fix it)

To rule out any possible doubts, here's a *DownloadAssistant* screenshot:

[image: Download Assistant]

Everything is checked, there are 2 items (not very relevant to this case) that are not showing (because the window is not sizeable), but they are checked (and **installed**).

**Background info**:

- When first installing *Unity*, there was no *VStudio 2017* version present on the computer, so it (*Community Edition*) was installed as part of *Unity* install process (I remember (at least) one *VStudio* related combo-box in the *Assistant*)
- Then, a *VStudio* patch was available; when preparing to install it, I realized that *VStudio* was installed on the default path (on *%SYSTEMDRIVE%*), which doesn't work for me, since it's a large product, so:

  - Uninstalled it
  - Reinstalled it (directly from [[VisualStudio]: Visual Studio Downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads)) on a different drive (and yes, I am aware that changing the install path, still installs a pretty big part like *Windows SDK* on *%SYSTEMDRIVE%*)
  - Since I thought that the above 2 steps would break the link between *Unity* and the new *VStudio*, I also reinstalled *Unity*. This time, there were no *VStudio* related check-boxes in the *Assistant* (seems normal to check if any piece of software that it needs to install, isn't already installed <sup>**1**</sup>). Later on, I also found a persistent (meaning that it's not wiped out at *Unity* uninstall time) *RegValue* (*HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Unity Technologies\Installer\Select_VisualStudio*) with a value of ***0*** (as opposed to a bunch of other values under the same key with values of *1*)
- After that, I reinstalled *Unity* several times, including reboots (not required) between uninstall / install, but no result (I also took a long shot of enabling the *RegVaue* above before starting *Assistant*)

A little debugging revealed that when trying to build (*PC Standalone*), *Unity* does something like this (don't mind the paths, it's how they're on my machine), that can be reproduced from *cmdline*:

*build_win.bat*:

> ```
> "E:\Install\x64\Unity\5.6.0f3\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\bin\mono.exe" "E:\Install\x64\Unity\5.6.0f3\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5\mcs.exe" "@args-win.txt"
> ```

*args_win.txt*:

```
-debug
-target:library
-nowarn:0169
-langversion:4
-out:Temp/Assembly-CSharp.dll
-unsafe
-optimize
-r:E:/Install/x64/Unity/5.6.0f3/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/GUISystem/Standalone/UnityEngine.UI.dll
-r:E:/Install/x64/Unity/5.6.0f3/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/Networking/Standalone/UnityEngine.Networking.dll
-r:E:/Install/x64/Unity/5.6.0f3/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/UnityAnalytics/UnityEngine.Analytics.dll
-define:UNITY_5_3_OR_NEWER
-define:UNITY_5_4_OR_NEWER
-define:UNITY_5_5_OR_NEWER
-define:UNITY_5_6_OR_NEWER
-define:UNITY_5_6_0
-define:UNITY_5_6
-define:UNITY_5
-define:UNITY_ANALYTICS
-define:ENABLE_AUDIO
-define:ENABLE_CACHING
-define:ENABLE_CLOTH
-define:ENABLE_DUCK_TYPING
-define:ENABLE_GENERICS
-define:ENABLE_PVR_GI
-define:ENABLE_MICROPHONE
-define:ENABLE_MULTIPLE_DISPLAYS
-define:ENABLE_PHYSICS
-define:ENABLE_RUNTIME_NAVMESH_BUILDING
-define:ENABLE_SPRITERENDERER_FLIPPING
-define:ENABLE_SPRITES
-define:ENABLE_TERRAIN
-define:ENABLE_RAKNET
-define:ENABLE_UNET
-define:ENABLE_LZMA
-define:ENABLE_UNITYEVENTS
-define:ENABLE_WEBCAM
-define:ENABLE_WWW
-define:ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_COLLAB
-define:ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_ADS
-define:ENABLE_CLOUD_HUB
-define:ENABLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID
-define:ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_UNET
-define:ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_BUILD
-define:ENABLE_CLOUD_LICENSE
-define:ENABLE_EDITOR_METRICS
-define:ENABLE_EDITOR_METRICS_CACHING
-define:ENABLE_NATIVE_ARRAY
-define:INCLUDE_DYNAMIC_GI
-define:INCLUDE_GI
-define:PLATFORM_SUPPORTS_MONO
-define:RENDER_SOFTWARE_CURSOR
-define:INCLUDE_PUBNUB
-define:ENABLE_PLAYMODE_TESTS_RUNNER
-define:ENABLE_SCRIPTING_NEW_CSHARP_COMPILER
-define:ENABLE_VIDEO
-define:UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
-define:UNITY_STANDALONE
-define:ENABLE_SUBSTANCE
-define:ENABLE_RUNTIME_GI
-define:ENABLE_MOVIES
-define:ENABLE_NETWORK
-define:ENABLE_CRUNCH_TEXTURE_COMPRESSION
-define:ENABLE_UNITYWEBREQUEST
-define:ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES
-define:ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_ANALYTICS
-define:ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_PURCHASING
-define:ENABLE_CLOUD_SERVICES_CRASH_REPORTING
-define:ENABLE_EVENT_QUEUE
-define:ENABLE_CLUSTERINPUT
-define:ENABLE_VR
-define:ENABLE_WEBSOCKET_HOST
-define:ENABLE_MONO
-define:NET_2_0_SUBSET
Assets/_Scripts/x.cs
-r:E:\Install\x64\Unity\5.6.0f3\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
-r:E:\Install\x64\Unity\5.6.0f3\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity\System.Xml.Linq.dll
-r:E:\Install\x64\Unity\5.6.0f3\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity\UnityScript.dll
-r:E:\Install\x64\Unity\5.6.0f3\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity\UnityScript.Lang.dll
-r:E:\Install\x64\Unity\5.6.0f3\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity\Boo.Lang.dll
-sdk:unity
```

*args_win.txt* is a copy of one of the *${PROJECT_ROOT}\Temp\UnityTempFile-**s (I'm going to refer to such a file as *utfile*), more precisely of the one that gets created when starting the build. The funky thing is that it's created from another (one of the 10+ identical created at project load time) *utfile* by (didn't do a through check, maybe there are additional lines as well) striping (and shuffling (*amestecating*)) some lines.

The obvious one (don't even have to check the source *utfile*) is: `-r:E:/Install/x64/Unity/5.6.0f3/Editor/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll`, which inserted in the above file, works perfectly. But I don't know how to instruct *Unity* not to strip it.

**Other facts** (more or less relevant):

- There are several other *VStudio* versions installed (*2010*, *2013*, *2015*), and more *VCRedist*s, but I seriously doubt that any of this would make a difference, since *VStudio* is only used for editing (e.g. launched by *Unity* when dblclicking a script)
- My computer also "suffers" from [[BT]: Has your Windows 10 Start menu stopped working? How to fix it](http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/computing/has-your-windows-10-start-menu-stopped-working-here-are-four-ways-to-fix-it-11364000314532) (I restart it ~once a week; after ~3-4 days the problem reappears), but this is happening for weeks before installing *Unity*

**Possible solutions**:

- Uninstall *Unity* and *VStudio*, and restore the original setup (if it still works) - not desirable
- Get an answer (here or on *Unity* forums, where I'm going to post the same question right away), and hopefully get to the bottom of it
- Start the painful process of debugging/monitoring ([[MS.Docs]: Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) (*ProcMon*) is an excellent tool) also, might involve disassembling *UnityDownloadAssistant-5.6.0f3.exe*, but there are no guarantees that it would yield a (favorable) result. Anyway, I think there is a (hidden for now) link between:

  - *VStudio* check-box not being present in *Assistant*, when *VStudio* already installed
  - Lack of the build parameters combo-boxes for *PC Standalone*
  - Stripping the *UnityEngine.dll* dependency when building
- A possible work plan / algorithm for fixing this would be (just theory):

  - Debugging the *Assistant* and identifying the resource (registry value, file, ...) queried for *VStudio* installation status
  - Tweak that resource to make *Assistant* "think" that *VStudio* is not installed; that would trigger the *VStudio* installer (and also make *Assistant* "mark" that this installation as suitable for *PC Standalone* builds), which would detect a previous installation (of course before this, the resource (if the same) needs to be untweaked) and would fail (another long shot here would be that *Assistant* doesn't check the return codes)
  - Let *Assistant* finish and hopefully everything will be fine

Any ideas are welcome.

**Side note <sup>1</sup>** (not related to question): While uninstalling/installing *Unity*, I noticed smth; if it's *Community Edition* specific, I can (sort of) understand it, but if not, then it's a quite **lame** bug / behavior:

- Have *Unity* installed (fully as above)
- Run the *Assistant* and don't change anything from previous installation (the parent *RegKey* of the *RegValue* that I mentioned above, makes sure of that by default). It will:

  - Download (and **overwrite** ???) any sub pkg (e.g. *UnitySetup-Linux-Support-for-Editor-5.6.0f3.exe*, *FacebookGamesArcade.msi*, ...); for me it was ~3GB+ (even if the **files were already there**)
  - Run every specified("checked") pkg / file
  - Remove (*UnitySetup64.exe*) any existing installation before installing (???)

Comment: do you have `using UnityEngine;` at the top of your script?

Comment: @Daco18s Of course. The script is syntactically correct, otherwise it wouldn't play/build and would be "red" in _VStudio_.

Comment: Just checking, as that's the first thing that sprung to mind.  Very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Long story

Apparently, there wasn't an *easy fix* (or at least I couldn't find any), so I started the "extremely challenging" process of uninstalling / reinstalling *Unity* and *VStudio* (with restarts after uninstall - to make sure that there are no "hidden" operations left hanging).

I started by looking at what the *Assistant* does under the hood, by specifying a custom download path, as in the image below:

[image: Assistant custom paths]

**Note**: The **installation paths are a little bit different from the ones in the question** because I changed them (since I had to reinstall the products why not make some use of it?), but those changes are not relevant.

In the specified folder there were a bunch(*~3GB*+) of downloaded files (executables), and a *batch* script that is the command line equivalent of the *Assistant*.

*install.bat*:

```
REM Run this script to automatically install or reinstall all packages,
REM as it's performed by the Unity Download Assistant.
REM Needs to be run with superuser permissions.

"UnitySetup64.exe" -UI=reduced /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
"UnityDocumentationSetup.exe" /S /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
"UnityStandardAssetsSetup.exe" /S /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
"UnityExampleProjectSetup.exe" /S
"vs_Community.exe" --productId "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community" --add "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedGame" --campaign "Unity3d_Unity" --passive
msiexec.exe /i "FacebookGamesArcade.msi" /qr LAUNCHEXE=FALSE
"UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-5.6.0f3.exe" /S /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
"UnitySetup-iOS-Support-for-Editor-5.6.0f3.exe" /S /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
"UnitySetup-AppleTV-Support-for-Editor-5.6.0f3.exe" /S /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
"UnitySetup-Linux-Support-for-Editor-5.6.0f3.exe" /S /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
"UnitySetup-Mac-Support-for-Editor-5.6.0f3.exe" /S /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
"UnitySetup-Metro-Support-for-Editor-5.6.0f3.exe" /S /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
"UnitySetup-UWP-IL2CPP-Support-for-Editor-5.6.0f3.exe" /S /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
"UnitySetup-Samsung-TV-Support-for-Editor-5.6.0f3.exe" /S /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
"UnitySetup-Tizen-Support-for-Editor-5.6.0f3.exe" /S /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
"UnitySetup-WebGL-Support-for-Editor-5.6.0f3.exe" /S /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
"UnitySetup-Facebook-Games-Support-for-Editor-5.6.0f3.exe" /S /D=e:\Install\x64\Unity\Community\5.6.0f3
```

The one that caught my eye was the *VStudio* related one:

```
"vs_Community.exe" --productId "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community" --add "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedGame" --campaign "Unity3d_Unity" --passive
```

As (some of) the launcher arguments didn't say much to me, I looked them up: [[MS.Docs]: Use command-line parameters to install Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017). So, I launched it by command line (without `--passive` tho get a chance of looking what features are selected), and I thought I've got it: the *Game development with Unity* was selected as in the image below (before, when I was installing *VStudio* "normally", I **didn't check** that box):

[image: Unity selection]

But the behavior **was the same** !!!

**Notes**:

- If you choose to install this option (and also install *Unity* yourself), make sure to uncheck *Unity editor*, to avoid installing it twice
- As I later found out (by reinstalling, of course), checking / unchecking *Game development with Unity* has absolutely no impact
- Also, the fact that *VStudio* wasn't installed on its default path (at some point I became paranoid and thought that there might be some *VStudio* hardcoded paths in *Unity* files) was not the cause

The next step that I did, was to recreate the initial scenario (where it used to work):

- Install *VStudio* with "my" initial options (e.g. *Game development with Unity* unchecked)
- Install *Unity* with default options - deleting its *RegKey* (that I mentioned in the question) prior to installation

and **it worked** !!!

Then I knew that one of the *Unity* components is screwing around with my settings, so on top of the basic installation (the contents of the *install.bat* til *vs_Community.exe*) I started installing all the other options, one by one, and after each component install check whether I am able to do a *PC Standalone* build, and ...

### Short story

It turns out that *Facebook Gameroom Build Support* (as showing in the *Assistant*) **was the root of all my problems**. So, another clean install of (both *VStudio* and) *Unity* (**without** the *Facebook* build support) works like a charm.

Now, the investigation is only half way done, I still need to find out **why** does this happen, but I'm going to stop here. If in the future, I'll need to build for *Facebook*, then I'll have to figure it out and make it work, but for now I won't. 
Note that for my (noobish) purpose, *Standalone* (*PC* since currently I'm on *Win*) builds are enough (and maybe *WebGL* as well to test from browser), but I installed all the others in case I want to play around with them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems introduced when adding Facebook Gameroom build support and is not yet fixed as of `2017.3.1f`.

Workaround:

1. Go to `Unity` folder (`C:\Program Files\Unity` on Windows x64)
2. Move `Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/Facebook` to the `Unity` folder, so now you have `Editor` and `Facebook` next to each other

By @jura_z at
https://forum.unity.com/threads/installing-facebook-gameroom-build-support-gives-loads-of-errors-when-building-to-windows-standalone.489495/